# Laravel show() parameter are null

Tags: laravel, laravel-routing

I am using Laravel version 5.6.26. My show() parameter get null value. Why? and how to solve it? Thank you

**web.php**

```
Route::get('/peoples', 'UsersController@index')->name('peoples');
Route::get('/peoples/{id?}', 'UsersController@show');
```

**UserController.php**

```
public function show(User $user)
    {
        $user = User::where('id', $user->id)->first();
        //$user = User::find($user->id)->first();
        return dd($user);
        //return view('profile',['user' => $user]);
    }
```

**user.blade.php** when I click `<a href="/peoples/{{$user->id}}" >` , it show null

```
<h4><a href="/peoples/{{$user->id}}" > {{$user->name}}</a></h4>
```

**result**

https://i.stack.imgur.com/Pvyd2.jpg

But if i do like this,I can get the value

```
public function show(User $user)
    {

        $user = User::where('id',1)->first();
        //$user = User::find($user->id)->first();
        return dd($user);
        //return view('profile',['user' => $user]);
    }
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow.  Standard practice (especially for short code snippets like those in your links) is to post the code directly in your question, as opposed to linking to a screenshot.  This makes it easier for others to help you by eliminating the need to navigate to a separate website or open up multiple browser tabs.  Please consider editing your question to reflect the above best practices.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The way you defined your `show` method i.e. `show(User $user)` is called route model binding if your variable name (`$user`) is similar to your route declaration. But your route declaration is `/peoples/{id?}` so the `User` instance is not created in your controller. So just rename the route declaration as `/peoples/{user?}`.

The use case of route model binding is you don't want to query/load the model related to a route parameter. So if you define the route the way I've mentioned you won't need the `$user = User::where('id', $user->id)->first();` query. Because Laravel will automatically instantiate that `$user` with the `User` model of `id` passed in the route.

If you want to query/load the `User` model manually then keep your existing route declaration as it is. And change your controller method declaration as `show($id = null)`

Answer (score 0):

You are injecting the `User` model in your controller, but not accessing the route path. If you want to access the `{id}` which set in the route, you have to access that in your controller too.

So your `UserController` will be something like

```
public function show(User $user, $id) 
{
     $user = User::where('id', $id)->first();
     dd($user);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

When you type hinted in your controller's method `show()` with `User`, Laravel will automatically inject that using [Service Container](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/container#automatic-injection).

Your **UserController.php**'s code should be:

```
public function show(User $user) {
    // no need to fetch user again. Laravel had already done that for you.
    dd($user);
    return view('profile', compact('user'));
}
```